# How to add import record functionality for one2many field in odoo

Tags: csv, import, odoo, xlsx, one2many

I want a functionality of adding the values for on2many field through file (bulk upload of the data), how can i achieve this in odoo-16 . If you anybody knows please explain about how can i achieve this properly

i tried using link:https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/import-xlsx-files-in-odoo-using-openpyxl, but i didn't understand it properly how can i use that to achieve my functionality. please provide the solution or suggestions to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to write data throw python this may help you:

```
(0, 0,  { values })    link to a new record that needs to be created with the given values dictionary
(1, ID, { values })    update the linked record with id = ID (write *values* on it)
(2, ID)                remove and delete the linked record with id = ID (calls unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and the link to it as well)
(3, ID)                cut the link to the linked record with id = ID (delete the relationship between the two objects but does not delete the target object itself)
(4, ID)                link to existing record with id = ID (adds a relationship)
(5)                    unlink all (like using (3,ID) for all linked records)
(6, 0, [IDs])          replace the list of linked IDs (like using (5) then (4,ID) for each ID in the list of IDs)
```

for example if your One2many field name is fee_ids with only name attribute and you want to create a new record and link to the fee_ids it should be done like below:

```
record.update({
   'fee_ids': [(0, 0, {'name': 'Sample Name'})]
})
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: As we can see odoo tree view, we have default import records for bulk upload that same feature i want for the on2many field tree view